# Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml

Tags: exception, ubuntu, filter, struts, tomcat6

I'm not that new to Java. I've done plenty of stuff with it before. But I'm migrating from PHP to Java Servlet/JSP (which I *am* new to) and I can't figure out this error to save my life. I installed Tomcat6 using Ubuntu 9.04's Synaptic Package Manager and it works like a charm. But when I put struts in my WEB-INF/lib directory and try to make a struts app, I get the below in the log file.

I used the struts-blank.war to start the project, so the web.xml is the same as provided in struts 2.1.8.1.

It appears that there is some issue with reading the struts-default.xml file.

Thanks in advance

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
>   Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.security.AccessControlContext
>   File: AccessControlContext.java
>   Method: checkPermission
>   Line: 342 - java/security/AccessControlContext.java:342:-1
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4359)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:145)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:769)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:926)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:889)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>       at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:177)
>   Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.security.AccessControlContext
>   File: AccessControlContext.java
>   Method: checkPermission
>   Line: 342 - java/security/AccessControlContext.java:342:-1
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
>       ... 36 more
>   Caused by: Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - Class: java.security.AccessControlContext
>   File: AccessControlContext.java
>   Method: checkPermission
>   Line: 342 - java/security/AccessControlContext.java:342:-1
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:902)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:143)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:110)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:168)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
>       ... 38 more
>   Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission xwork.saxParserFactory read)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:342)
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
>       at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:669)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:78)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:893)
>       ... 42 more

Answer (score 2):

I had a brain storm and figured this out myself. Although I don't think this is the most secure solution, but it works for my purposes and I'm not that concerned because it's a local dev server that only listens on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1).

Anyway, the solution is to add this to the bottom of /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/50local.policy

> grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/-" {
>           permission java.security.AllPermission;
>   };